# C# date time arithmetic over flow error

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have written a code for store the current date & time value. It was working the day before yesterday exactly as I wanted. But today it shows error `"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. The statement has been terminated."`

Can any body help me? Here is my code,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string q;
    q = "insert into tbl_MR(RequirementFor,Category,MRNO,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)values(@rf,@cat,@mr,@cb,@cd)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rf", CCddl.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mr", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb", Session["loginid"].ToString());
    string cd1, date1;
    cd1 = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(cd1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd", date1.ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    string alertmessage = "";
    alertmessage = "Component Details Saved";
    this.CreateMessageAlert(this, alertmessage, "alertKey");
    con.Close();  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert a date to a string in order to send it to SQL Server.

Instead of all this:

```
string cd1, date1;
cd1 = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(cd1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd", date1.ToString());
```

Just do this:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to check whether the `DateTime` is within the valid range; `DateTime` has a minimum date of `0000/01/01` whereas the SQL datetime's minimum date is `1753/01/01`. The 'arithmetic overflow' error can also occur in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `date1` format to `yyyy/MM/dd` or `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Yesterday was June 12th, 2012. What was actually being inserted into your database was probably December 6th, 2012 (12/06 vs. 06/12). Now that today's the 13th, you are getting the exception because there is no 13th month.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a culture info discrepancy. You could try modifying the ToString() method of the date to a different format.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cd", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```